# Copy streams using rdbuf fails on empty input

Tags: c++, stream, ostream

It is a well known method to copy a stream into another using `rdbuf`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream in{"/tmp/foo.txt"};
  std::cerr << in.rdbuf();
  std::cerr << "Done\n";
}
```

However, this breaks (= sets the bad bit) my `cerr` when `/tmp/foo.txt` is empty.  As a result, `Done\n` is not displayed.

Why is that?  Observed with G++/libstdc++/GNU Linux and Clang++/libc++/OS X.

Answer (score 5):

That seems to be the defined behaviour - see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt:

> If no characters were inserted, executes setstate(failbit)

I agree it's a bit unhelpful.

Comment: Totally unhelpful indeed :)  Would someone happen to know why the standard is this way?

Comment: Ugh, that was a bug in cppreference,  it sets failbit ([ostream.inserters]/9, or /8 in earlier). The outcome is the same for OP though.

Comment: @Cubbi Oh, thanks for the correction. I see you fixed it there; I've amended my answer. Laziness on my part not going to the standard text.

Comment: At least it means it is easier to distinguish this form of failure from e.g. a null `streambuf`, which does set `badbit`, and it makes slightly more sense. The most obvious thing to do is just to clear it after the write, which seems a bit of a shame.